# Adding controls to a from C# 2015, this.Controls.Add(bla) method not found?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        this.Controls.Add(wb);
    }
}
```

This results in an error:

> 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'MainWindow' could be found

Whats wrong here?
This is a WPF Application.
I'm new to C#. 
I find it on internet that to add controls to the form the function is

```
this.Controls.Add(fdfdf)
```

But here `this` doesn't contain `Controls`.

Comment: Controls is probably from WinForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF it should be `Children`. In WPF you need to add items as **Childrens** of layout panels like your main `Grid`. For example if you have a `Grid` set it's name to `grid1` and then in the code you can:

```
grid1.Children.Add(fdfdf)
```

Comment: can't i add directly to the form?

Comment: @SadeepDarshana...No. In WPF you need to use Container controls like `Grid`,`StackPanel` and.... . You could add controls to the main `Grid` but you should set a name for that first.

Comment: is it the WPF that is used more commanly now when developing windows applications or is it the Forms??

Comment: If you are learning now, I would recomend you go the WPF way. It is a modern technology compared to winforms and it is native in Windows 10 @SadeepDarshana

Answer (score 2):

You can add a component like your WebBrowser directly to the content of the Window.

In WPF you are doing it like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        this.Content = wb;
    }
}
```

But I suggest to do this via the XAML.